# Ordering dependencies of dependencies

Tags: algorithm, graph, dependencies

I currently have a system that has so called 'nodes' and each node has dependencies.
My issues is when deleting a node, it's dependencies must exist so now I need to figure out the right order in which to delete the nodes.
What would be a way of doing this? (final language implementation will be PHP)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially the problem of finding the [topological ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) of the directed graph where each edge represents a dependency (so you'll have an edge from `E` to `A` because `A` depends on `E`, similarly for the rest).

> A topological sort (sometimes abbreviated topsort or toposort) or topological ordering of a directed graph is a linear ordering of its vertices such that for every directed edge uv from vertex u to vertex v, u comes before v in the ordering.

One approach to this problem involves repeatedly picking a node with no incoming edges, and then removing all the outgoing edges from that node (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) for more details).